# Why this word can't be grep?

Tags: linux, grep, less, busybox

I have access to busybox only, v `1.27`.

I'm trying to use a huge TXT file I extracted from a PDF document as a TXT dictionary, to be console friendly. The word I'm trying to get is the very first word of the line. What's next on the line, is the definition.

```
Word I'm grepping for:

patético
```

The one liner I'm using is this:

```
cat ./rae.txt | grep '^patético'
```

`cat` is being used because I have a quicker access to delete the word I'm looking for and that's more efficient. It saves a couple of keystrokes by just deleting the last part of the line, the term.

Most of the time I get the definition of the word I'm searching, for example `anhelo`.

```
$ grep -e '^anhelo' ./rae.txt
anhelo. (Del lat. anhelus). 1. m. Deseo vehemente.     
anheloso, sa. (Del lat. anhelosus). 1. adj. Que tiene o siente anhelo. Anhelosos de con-   cluir. 2. adj. Propio de lo que muestra anhelo. Mirada, búsqueda anhelosa. 3. adj. Dicho de la   respiración: Frecuente y fatigosa. 4. adj. desus. Que respira de este modo.
```

As you can see, each line has the definition, `anhelo` and `anheloso`.

First I thought the issue was the dot `.` and/or comma `,` right after the word, I assumed it was being expanded or interpreted as a special character and not as plain text. But is not the case.

My questions are:

**Why I can't grep `^patético`?**
**Why this does not work?**

```
grep -e '^patético' ./rae.txt
```

The text I'm running `grep` on is:

```
patería. 1. f. coloq. Chile y Perú. Muestra ocasional y fingida de amistad.     

paternal. (De paterno). 1. adj. Propio del afecto, cariño o solicitud de padre.     

paternalismo. 1. m. Tendencia a aplicar las formas de autoridad y protección propias del   padre en la familia tradicional a relaciones sociales de otro tipo; políticas, laborales, etc. U. m.   en sent. peyor.     

paternalista. 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que adopta el paternalismo como forma de   conducta. U. t. c. s. 2. adj. Que responde o parece responder a dicha actitud.     

paternalmente. 1. adv. m. De modo propio o digno de un padre.     

paternidad. (Del lat. paternitas, -atis). 1. f. Cualidad de padre. 2. f. Tratamiento que en   algunas órdenes dan los religiosos inferiores a los padres condecorados de su orden, y que   los seculares dan por reverencia a todos los religiosos en general, considerándolos como   padres espirituales.     

paterno, na. (Del lat. paternus). 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo al padre. 2. adj. Propio   del padre. 3. adj. Derivado de él.  V. casa paterna     

paternóster. (Del lat. Pater noster, Padre nuestro, palabras con que principia la oración   dominical). 1. m. Oración del padrenuestro. 2. m. Padrenuestro que se dice en la misa, y es   una de las partes de ella. 3. m. Cada uno de los aditamentos de alambre que se adaptan al   chambel para aumentarle su capacidad de pesca. 4. m. Chambel ya preparado con estos   artilugios. 5. m. coloq. Nudo gordo y muy apretado.     

patero, ra. (De pato1). 1. adj. Chile y Perú. Adulador, lisonjeador. U. t. c. s. 2. m.   Cazador de patos salvajes.     

pateta. (De pata1). 1. m. coloq. diablo (|| príncipe de los ángeles rebelados). Ya se lo   llevó pateta. No lo hiciera pateta. 2. m. coloq. Persona que tiene un vicio en la conformación   de los pies o de las piernas. 3. m. pl. u. c. sing. Méx. diablo (|| príncipe de los ángeles rebela-   dos). EL patetas.     

patéticamente. 1. adv. m. De modo patético.     

patético, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, y este del gr. o, que impresiona, sensible). 1. adj. Que   es capaz de mover y agitar el ánimo infundiéndole afectos vehementes, y con particularidad   dolor, tristeza o melancolía.     

patetismo. 1. m. Cualidad de patético.     

patí. (De or. guar.). 1. m. Arg. y Ur. Pez grande de río, de color gris azulado con man-   chas oscuras. 2. m. C. Rica. Especie de empanada rellena de carne o papas.     

-patía. (Del lat. -pathia, y este del gr. a, de la raíz -, sufrir, experimentar). 1. elem. com-   pos. Significa 'sentimiento', 'afección' o 'dolencia'. Homeopatía, telepatía.     

patiabierto, ta. (De pata1 y abierto). 1. adj. coloq. Que tiene las piernas torcidas e irreg-   ulares, y separadas una de otra.
```

By the way, is not just `patético` is every word with a `tilde`; in this word is `é`.
My system doesn't have UTF-8 support, nor a language package installed. I assumed this should not be a problem, because letters are just a stream of bytes and also that I don't have issues if I utilize `less` to search for words not showing up with `grep`.

**EDIT0**

locale

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

file -i rae.txt

```
rae.txt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**EDIT1**

Console codepage

```
C
POSIX

ANSI_X3.110-1983
ANSI_X3.4-1968
ISO-8859-1
ISO-8859-15
ISO-8859-2
```

**EDIT 2**
After processing `rae.txt` with `iconv` to be `ISO8859-1`

```
./rae-iso88591.txt: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: @Inian Is from `busybox 1.27`. Not the `GNU` one. So I suppose the version is `1.27` same as `busybox`.

Comment: I don't have a busybox installation of `grep`, but the above works on both GNU and FreeBSD versions

Comment: Can you give `LC_CTYPE="UTF-8" grep -e '^patético' ./rae.txt` a shot?

Comment: @Inian Did it, no output. I think, it's because there is no fonts, locale nor any kind of support for something beyond `C`. It's like 1980's computing, haha.

Comment: with ASCII text, letters **are** just a stream of bytes (actually, just a single byte each, for ascii).   With unicode text, things are much more complicated, and you need a unicode locale installed and the system needs to be configured to use it.

Comment: @cas So, If I convert the file to be one of the arcane charsets like `ISO-8859-1` I might have the possibility to get the correct result? Because is like ASCII but each byte is represented in a different way?

Comment: yeah, it's possible you might have some luck with `iconv` (piping iconv's output into grep).     or it might be easier to just use perl instead of grep - e.g. `perl -e 'print if /^patético/' rae.txt` (or maybe use `pcregrep` instead).  I don't know for sure, I've never tried working on unicode text on a system with disabled or broken unicode support.

Comment: @cas I'll try. Besides, what I tried before was to use a pattern to search for the word. Like `grep -e '^pat?tico'` but it doesn't yield results. What would be the right way to do it with `utf-8`? To just replace that one letter with a `tilde` (`é`).

Comment: In utf8 any non-ascii character is a sequence of 2-4 bytes in the 160-255 range of 8bit chars; in your case, é (233) is 195/169 (Â©), so wildcarding one byte does not match your string.

Comment: @jarnosz That's what I thought. But then, why the regular "match all" wild card does not work `*`? `grep -e '^pat*tico' ./rae.txt`

Comment: @abacox Grep does not use wildcard characters. It uses regular expressions `^pat*tico` means: `p` at the beginning, followed by `a`, followed by 0 or more `t` characters, followed by `tico`.

Comment: I expect `^pat.\+tico` would probably work. But... that's got its own problems!

Comment: @mattdm I tried it. Pretty much is the same output I got when trying just `'^pat'`. It throws all words starting with  `pat`.

Comment: @jarnosz TinyCore Linux v12 x86_64. My main OS. But, I do use other systems with almost the same configuration, barebones `busybox` and linux kernel and/or *BSD.

Comment: @mattdm, `\+` is undefined in standard basic regex. It only works in GNU. If you want an equivalent for the ERE `.+`, use `..*` (or in general `a\{1,\}` for `a+`)

Comment: @jarnosz Thank you. FYI I've found the answer I needed with your guy's help. Please, check the answer I posted.

Comment: FWIW, you state *tilde*, but it is an *acute* accent in `é`. This is a tilde: `~`, this is an acute `´`, this is a grave `\``.

Comment: for us, spanish speakers, the acute accent is called "tilde"; the glyph over the n is technically called "virgulilla", but this terminology is not quite strictly enforced.

Comment: @ilkkachu Are you sure about that? I was using busybox to test, and I'm pretty sure "naked" `+` just works in the _extended_ regex (-E flag), and you need `\+` for basic regex. I just tested with `echo 'foo' | busybox grep '^fo\+$'` and... it seems right? Happy to be corrected here. I always have to look up (or test!) which things have to be escaped when!

Comment: @mattdm, ok, could be that it's more commonly implemented than I thought. Anyway, it's not actually standard, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> is undefined, except for _[`(){}1-9`]_" and special characters are listed as just `.[\*^$`. The precedence table explicitly lists `\{`, `\(`, `*` etc., but _not_ `\+`. With the tools I have on Mac, `grep` supports it, but `sed` doesn't. But if they ask me, people should just use ERE anyway. ;)

Comment: @ilkkachu It's possible that it's just working with my busybox because it's linked to glibc, and uses that implementation, and that busybox with some other libc might not work the same way? (Which, by the way, is _terrible_. Yay, standards!)

Comment: @mattdm, yes. Though well, GNU stuff has extensions, so if glibc does too, then, well, that's not too odd. They might or might not have a switch to disable it, at least `POSIXLY_CORRECT` tells `getopt()` to not reorder options first.

Comment: Turns out, that TinyCore has UTF-8 at the GUI, but Latin1 at console: that may explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, not sure if this is your issue, but one possible reason for not finding the correct line is the two encodings for the letter é. There's the Unicode character U+00E9 (Latin small letter E with acute), which is the whole glyph in itself; and there's the combination of `e` and U+0301 (Combining acute accent). The UTF-8 representations of those would be `c3 a9` and `65 cc 81` in hex.

Copying the text from your question, the letter comes off as U+00E9.

So:

```
$ grep ^patético file.txt    # no output
$ grep ^patético file.txt
patético, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, ...
```

And of course depending on how the system is set up, there might be issues with entering the character in the first place, but you could work around that with something like:

```
$ grep $'^pat\xc3\xa9tico' file.txt
patético, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, ...
```

Converting to ISO 8859-1 turns it into the single byte `e9`, so in the `C` locale, a single `.` will be enough to match it. Though at least on my system, with an UTF-8 locale, the lone `e9` byte would be an invalid character and `.` would not match it.

Though of course it's still an invalid character for my UTF-8 terminal, so the output looks like this:

```
$ iconv -f utf8 -t latin1 file.txt  | LC_ALL=C grep $'^pat.tico'
pat�tico, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, ...
```

Comment: Would you say that is better to work with the `TXT` archive according to the settings on the system? Like, if `UTF-8` is supported then have the file encoded in such way, same case if just `C` is supported, to have the file in `ISO8859-1`, and so on?

Comment: I was taking a closer look at the hex grepping you've done there. What a awesome way to get around the issue without re-encoding the content.

Comment: +1. You could grep for both characters at once with `grep '^pat\(é\|é\)tico'` (or as an extended regex with `grep -E '^pat(é|é)tico'`. or GNU grep's perl-compatible regex with a non-capturing group: `grep -P '^pat(?:é|é)tico'`).   You can still use `$'...'` instead of `'...'` to use the hex codes inside the parentheses if you want.

Comment: and (i should have included this earlier because it's obvious, duh) you can use bracket expressions like `pat[eéé]tico` in your regex too.

Comment: @cas, yes, though if the data is in UTF-8 and the locales aren't UTF-8-aware, then the bracket expression may may start picking the individual bytes of the encoding. The C locale was mentioned, and where I tried `echo 'á' | LC_ALL=C grep -o '[eé]'` picks just the 0xc3 byte... So the `(e|é|é)` version may be safer.

Comment: That's what i get for posting so late at night, I suppose.  So...bracket expressions match any of the individual characters (so multi-byte chars will work in a unicode locale), but without a working unicode locale (i.e. support for multi-byte chars), they match *any* of the individual bytes making up a character (because without unicode support, `é` is not interpreted as the character `é`, it is interpreted as two bytes `C3` and `A9`).  A capture group with alternation, however, isn't limited to just matching individual bytes, it matches the exact byte sequences: `C3A9` (é) or `65CC81` (é).

Answer (score 2):

As @cas suggested, piping the utf-8 input through iconv may do the trick. Try

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t CP1252 rae.txt | grep -e '^patético'
```

Just make sure that the console codepage is Win1252 or Latin1 to make it work.

Tested with busybox-w32 v1.33 on Win10, and v1.29 on TinyCore10.

If you are running on a real flavor of *nix, you should check and/or fix the codepage of your console, just as @Inian hinted at, to make it work.

*Addendum*

Please notice that you may avoid guessing the CharCodes of the letters in clean 8bit codepages simply by searching

```
cat rae.txt | grep -e '^pat.tico'
```

or by two (or as many as necessary) dots on UTF-8.

```
cat rae.txt | grep -e '^pat..tico'
```

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you. Done it, no luck. Now I'm trying to get the expansion trick to work `^pat?tico`. For that I'm aiming to get a 7bit encoding. So far `UTF-7`, `ISO8859-1`, `CP1252` didn't make the trick. :/

Comment: Oh!, I did not mentioned it, but I added the console codepages. It seems that at least `ISO8859-1` should work. Please see my edit.

Comment: @abacox you're confusing wildcards (i.e. shell globs) with regex.  In regex, `?` doesn't mean "any character".  It means the the previous character (or capture group) is optional (or, "zero-or-one". compare with `*` which means "zero-or-more").  For "any character", use `.` - so `^pat.tico`

Answer (score 0):

YES! THANK YOU GUYS. :)

What finally worked out for me was converting the file from `UTF-8` to `ISO8859-1`. And using **regular expressions** instead of wild cards. I finally got the definition I'm looking for.

```
grep -e '^pat.tico' ./rae-iso88591.txt
```

Yields

```
patético, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, y este del gr. o, que impresiona, sensible). 1. adj. Que   es capaz de mover y agitar el ánimo infundiéndole afectos vehementes, y con particularidad   dolor, tristeza o melancolía.
```

Comment: i prefer converting utf8 to cp1252 because latin1 (8859-1) covers a narrower range, and I lose some characters in the process.

Comment: Thank you. I tried with `CP1252` and it does work as well. I'll take your word for it and will stick with `CP1252`.

Answer (score -2):

Some time if it contains extra spaces in beginning so we used below wild card

```
grep "[[:space:]]*\?patético," file
```

output

```
patético, ca. (Del lat. patheticus, y este del gr. o, que impresiona, sensible). 1. adj. Que   es capaz de mover y agitar el ánimo infundiéndole afectos vehementes, y con particularidad   dolor, tristeza o melancolía.
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would work and `^patético` does not? You don't actually say that `^patético` does not work on your system.